# Macro to Conditionally Format rows based on cell contents

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a file that I export every morning. I've written a macro to delete unnecessary columns, and to remove hyphens from the phone numbers that are exported in the file. My last step is to highlight rows in which the phone number matches one of those in my list of Do Not Call numbers.

The bottom section SHOULD highlight rows in the sheet where C(n) equals any of the following values (phone numbers...)

```
Sub Annihilation()
'
' Annihilation Macro
' Highlight bad numbers, formats worksheet.
'

'
Range("B:B,D:D,E:E,G:G").Select
Range("G1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR($C2= 2025211493, $C2=2063919340, $C2=2096568626, $C2=2184943359, $C2=2535203630, $C2=2533306498, $C2=4055763188, $C2=4057014173, $C2=4235861076, $C2=5019450123, $C2=5036781060, $C2=5036071088, $C2=5094532476, $C2=5138697827, $C2=5175070612, $C2=5409662174, $C2=5592714006, $C2=5613334173, $C2=5626224977, $C2=6152069720, $C2=6194611018, $C2=6206408997, $C2=7086919068, $C2=7028252742, $C2=7173546777, $C2=7609497400, $C2=7634446852, $C2=7702050218, $C2=8002263696, $C2=8017841482,  $C2=8015756500, $C2=8063641273, $C2=8179243829, $C2=8436654968, $C2=8476561100, $C2=8608150728, $C2=8602171111, $C2=8669710959, $C2=8883420784, $C2=9197901354, $C2=9199349948, $C2=9519245300, $C2=9703020157)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

End Sub
When I run this, rows are highlighted in the color specified, but the rows selected aren't the ones that contain any of these numbers.

Any help at all on this? Is the code incorrect?

Comment: Can you post all the code regarding the formatting? It seems you have missed an 'End With'. It would be better to see more of the relevant code.

Comment: @MacroMarc, see updated original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly confused. I don't see how the code above code actually causes several rows to be formatted in any way at all.
Anyway, here is my suggestion:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A2:G6") 'figure out how to set this to your appropriate range
         'It should be a range starting at the first cell in the data range, and end in the last cell

r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR($C2= 2025211493, $C2=2063919340, $C2=2096568626, $C2=2184943359, $C2=2535203630, $C2=2533306498, $C2=4055763188, $C2=4057014173, $C2=4235861076, $C2=5019450123, $C2=5036781060, $C2=5036071088, $C2=5094532476, $C2=5138697827, $C2=5175070612, $C2=5409662174, $C2=5592714006, $C2=5613334173, $C2=5626224977, $C2=6152069720, $C2=6194611018, $C2=6206408997, $C2=7086919068, $C2=7028252742, $C2=7173546777, $C2=7609497400, $C2=7634446852, $C2=7702050218, $C2=8002263696, $C2=8017841482,  $C2=8015756500, $C2=8063641273, $C2=8179243829, $C2=8436654968, $C2=8476561100, $C2=8608150728, $C2=8602171111, $C2=8669710959, $C2=8883420784, $C2=9197901354, $C2=9199349948, $C2=9519245300, $C2=9703020157)"
r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With r.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
End With
r.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for your help, @macromarc. The first few lines were just to delete extra columns... the bit about formatting cells on certain conditions was the part that wasn't working. It is now, thanks to you!

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your FormatConditions Formula1 line to be $C1 instead of $C2, since you're applying this to Cells.  Otherwise it is looking at one row down instead of the same row:

```
"=OR($C1={2025211493,2063919340,2096568626,2184943359,2535203630,2533306498,4055763188,4057014173,4235861076,5019450123,5036781060,5036071088,5094532476,5138697827,5175070612,5409662174,5592714006,5613334173,5626224977,6152069720,6194611018,6206408997,7086919068,7028252742,7173546777,7609497400,7634446852,7702050218,8002263696,8017841482, 8015756500,8063641273,8179243829,8436654968,8476561100,8608150728,8602171111,8669710959,8883420784,9197901354,9199349948,9519245300,9703020157})"
```

Comment: Bracket missing at the end of your list. Would this not be an array formula though? Can conditional formatting deal with it if it is?

Comment: Nevermind about the array formula. Tested it on a regular cell and worked perfectly without array formula. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing closing bracket, it has been added.  Glad to hear it is working for you

Comment: @tigeravatar When I change the line to that, I get the following message: "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. The option to debug highlights the lines ' Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _ "=OR($C1={2025211493,2063919340,2096568626,2184943359,2535203630, ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use 1 column to store ALL your numbers - color each group for easy spotting.

Put the NO call numbers on top.

1 cell =xxxx or whatever unique text to act as visible separator.

and below them and all the numbers you want to check to call or not.

Select Your Column > DATA TAB > Remove duplicates

The original no call numbers stay on top as they are identified and the rest is compared against them and removed.

Then you can select the column F5 and select and delete all empty rows should you need to consolidate. And again your No Calls remain on top, whatever remains below the separator cell is a clear to call.

In case you want to ease navigation in such a column view freeze about 10 of top rows and use them for nav links only:

Such as
**=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#",CELL("Address",$A$11)),"TO TOP")**

**=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#",CELL("Address",INDEX($A$1:$B$1000,MATCH("xxxx",$A$1:$B$1000,0)+0))),"TO SEPARATOR")**

where xxxx is the separator your are looking for - this thing simply finds where the separator address is should it move and it will move should change the list. Change the +0 if you want to be offset to +- location.